# For loop for image sampling in multiple directories

Tags: r, dataframe, raster

This is probably a simple R question but I can't seem to get this for loop to work. I have a script that takes a series of images in a directory and applies a spatial extract with coordinates for a single band of each image, then writes out a table based on those values. Ideally, I'd like to loop through all of the images in all the directories and just append all the data in a single csv, but for now I just included the write_delim inside the for loop. I can get it to work for a single index, i.e. when I place an integer like "5" into all the i slots. Here's the script. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

indir <- "/Volumes/Seagate Expansion Drive/MASS STORAGE/AMSRU/data/"
outdir <- "/Volumes/Seagate Expansion Drive/MASS STORAGE/AMSRU/output/"
coords <- shapefile("/Volumes/Seagate Expansion Drive/MASS STORAGE/AMSRU/data/points.shp")
dirs <- dir("/Volumes/Seagate Expansion Drive/MASS STORAGE/AMSRU/", pattern = "^[20]")

i <- 1 #initialize the directory loop
for(i in 1:length(dirs)) {
  #set working directory in subfolder
  wd <- setwd(paste0(indir,dirs[i])) 
  #gather all images
  rastlist <- list.files(path = wd, pattern='.tif', all.files=TRUE, full.names=FALSE)
 
 #extract coordinates from band 5 of all rasters 
  VODrasters <- lapply(rastlist, raster, band=5)       # pull band 5 into rasterlist
  VODstack <- stack(VODrasters)                        # convert to raster stack
  VODcoords <- raster::extract(VODstack, coords)       # extract

  #construct dataframe of VOD values
  df <- as.data.frame(map_dfr(.x = VODcoords,
                            .f = ~ enframe(x = .x,
                                           name = NULL,
                                           value = "VOD"),
                            .id = "ID"))
  df <- within(df, ID <- rep(1:length(rastlist), each=length(coords)) )
  df <- df[!df$VOD == "-999", ]                #remove NULL values 
  df <- within(df, day <- as.numeric(ID)+as.numeric(substr(rastlist[1],17,19))-1) %>%  # add day of year column from the name of first file and the ID, because some data acquisition does't begin with day "1".
        within(year <- dirs[i])  #add year
 
  #write out a VOD values file
  write_delim(df, paste0(outdir,"VOD", dirs[i], ".csv"), delim = ",")
  print(paste(dirs[i],"completed"))   #progress report

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example*. The first step I would take is to identify what your problem really is by dividing your code better.

If you can run this part

```
indir <- "/Volumes/Seagate Expansion Drive/MASS STORAGE/AMSRU/data/"
outdir <- "/Volumes/Seagate Expansion Drive/MASS STORAGE/AMSRU/output/"
coords <- shapefile("/Volumes/Seagate Expansion Drive/MASS STORAGE/AMSRU/data/points.shp")
dirs <- dir("/Volumes/Seagate Expansion Drive/MASS STORAGE/AMSRU/", pattern = "^[20]")

library(raster)
out <- list()
for(i in 1:length(dirs)) {
  wd <- setwd(paste0(indir,dirs[i])) 
  rastlist <- list.files(path = wd, pattern='.tif', all.files=TRUE, full.names=FALSE)
  VODrasters <- lapply(rastlist, raster, band=5)       # pull band 5 into rasterlist
  VODstack <- stack(VODrasters)                        # convert to raster stack
  out[[i]] <- raster::extract(VODstack, coords)       # extract
}
```

You can do then do `do.call(rbind, out)` or `lapply(out, f)` where `f` is a function with the next steps you want to take. My guess is that it is in these next steps. Without example data I cannot comment, it looks like a complicated way to do something rather simple.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The directory structure is like this:

topfolder/
   year1/image1.tif, image2.tif,...imagexxx.tif
   year2/image1.tif, image2.tif,...imagexxx.tif
   .
   .
   yearX/image1.tif, image2.tif, ... imagexxx.tif

Each of the images are in geotif format and I need to grab the raster values at the same coordinates for every image.